# DNS SOA response: googleDNS returns endless loop

Tags: dns, soa

I'm writing my own dns server (its close to the pi hole project but with some different / additional features) and now im facing a (for me) strange problem:

basically i want to do a PTR request for an IP to the external dns server (tried with 208.67.222.222 and 8.8.8.8)

the problem is, that I'm ending up in a endless loop, by getting a SOA response, where the primary name server is the same as the requested domain (i guess the screenshot is more precise)

My base idea, as i already mentioned, is to get all / some domains for a given ip address. Therefore I'm sending a PTR request to the (start) DNS server, where the query is "[IP address (reversed)].in-addr.arpa". As expected, the answer is a SOA answer, which should give me the information of which name server might have the knowledge to answer this question. Well, this name server is resolved as a CNAME and to query him, i need his IP address. Therefore i query the (start) DNS to resolve the domain of the new DNS server. And this is exactly my problem: I end up in having a endless loop, cause the (start) DNS just answers with a SOA response, where the target name server is the same as the requested domain... Am i missing something? (well i guess so, but what?)

[image]

I was expecting that it should act something like this:

```
[dns1] -> SOA response (a.doma.in) -> [me]
[me] -> CNAME (a.doma.in) -> [dns1]
[dns1] -> CNAME response (a.doma.in: 123.123.123.123) -> [me]
[me] -> PTR -> [123.123.123.123]
[123.123.123.123] -> PTR answer -> [me]
```

But the reality is this:

```
[dns1] -> SOA response (a.doma.in) -> [me]
[me] -> CNAME (a.doma.in) -> [dns1]
[dns1] -> SOA response (a.doma.in) -> [me]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're likely having is that the dns address in the SOA is an A record, and not a CNAME. You're creating a loop by looking for a CNAME

You're asking to resolve a name server against a domain that you're trying to resolve the name server of. (as you've already seen)

The SOA name server is *ALWAYS* an A record.

Looking to resolve www.example.com using dig, the flow goes like this -

```
   dig soa example.com
   dig A sns.dns.icann.org.
   dig www.example.com @192.0.32.162
```

Edited to add

The DNS SOA record looks like this when queried in dig

`example.com.            3600    IN      SOA     sns.dns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. 2019041059 7200 3600 1209600 3600`

These are broken down like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOA_record)

```
Name
retry interval
zone class
name server
email address of administrator (with @ replaced with .)
serial number
refresh
retry
expire
TTL
```

You should directly query the name server record for the list of name servers, and then select one of those.

Comment: thx for your answer, but im not sure if i understand you correctly, the SOA response doesnt contain any IP adress (isnt that what a type A record is?), therefore i have to look up the domain of the SOA response "primary name server", but who can resolve the ip of the primary name server? btw i saw on some web-pages that the ip address of the primary name server of the soa response is resolved in the "additionalRR" section of the dns response, but i never saw it myself, is there a way to request this?

Comment: sorry, was on holidays with no internet... i'm still not sure what you mean, yea, the SOA response looks like this, and that's the problem, i don't get any IP address; only a name server. I need to resolve the name server to query him to get the answer i was asking for, and if i query the part "name server" in your example, i get again a SOA answer with "name server"... obviously i'm missing something but i'm still not able to see what...

Comment: @Svhorsch  In the example above, sns.dns.icann.org. is the address of the primary nameserver. This is listed as a FQDN so you need to resolve that A record to then be able to resolve the list of NS records.